# About Linux Mint 18

Tags: discussion

I installed Linux Mint 18 on a separate partition on my PC.
When I want to ask a question about any problem I encounter:

- Can I do so in Ask Ubuntu?
- Or should I use the Linux Mint forums?

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate based on the idea that you're asking about problems you may encounter installing or using Mint. But if that's not what you mean--for example, if you're asking if you can get help here accessing your Mint partition from Ubuntu--then please **[edit]** this to clarify that, because that would be a different question. See also [Are half-Minty questions allowed?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14553/are-half-minty-questions-allowed)

Answer (score 4):

From Ask Ubuntu Help Center [What topics can I ask about here?](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions that you should avoid:
>
> Linux Mint, Elementary OS, Backtrack, Gnome-Remix (prior to 13.04), budgie-remix (16.04 and 16.10) and other Linux distributions (try our friends at [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)).

For questions about Elementary OS try [Elementary OS Stack Exchange](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/).