# Can you talk about Ubuntu-based Distros on Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion

For example, can you ask questions about OSes like Pop!_OS by System76 on this website, or can you only talk about Ubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, etc. only?

Comment: In short: Nope.

Comment: In long: You *can* "talk about" them. They can be mentioned or referenced, or compared, or used as an example of something you (eg) want to replicate... But the core of questions and answers should be about and for Ubuntu.

Comment: Related (regarding Oli's very good point): [Are half-Minty questions allowed?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14553/are-half-minty-questions-allowed)